# Scipy's solve_ivp can't seem to handle additional arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy

When using a simple example from the `solve_ivp` docs page itself (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html#scipy.integrate.solve_ivp):

```
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp

def lotkavolterra(t, z, a, b, c, d):
    x, y = z
    return [a*x - b*x*y, -c*y + d*x*y]

sol = solve_ivp(lotkavolterra, [0, 15], [10, 5], args=(1.5, 1, 3, 1), dense_output=True)
```

I get the following error:

```
return np.asarray(fun(t, y), dtype=dtype)
TypeError: lotkavolterra() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'a', 'b', 'c', and 'd'
```

Is something wrong with the `solve_ivp` implementation, or is the example that is given in the docs page incorrect? I've been trying to solve a similar issue (passing two numpy arrays in as additional arguments) for the past hour, but when I tried to see if a simpler example worked, I was amazed to see that it failed too. Am I going crazy, or is the above example failing for others as well?

Comment: i'm getting proper output from you code

Comment: The `args` parameter was added to `solve_ivp` in SciPy version 1.4.  I suspect you have an older version.  You can check which version you are using with `import scipy; print(scipy.__version__)`

Comment: Thanks Warren, updating `scipy` did the trick.